# Ignore exception in stream operations

Tags: java, java-stream

Assuming you have an exception (checked/unchecked) in a stream operation
and you want to ignore from now on this element.
The stream must not be aborted, just ignoring elements throwing exceptions.
I explicitly avoid saying skip, because it is a stream operation.

So the example is using the `map()` operation for demonstration.
Here I have a division by zero (for example), so the "map" should skip this
element.

As an example:

```
@Test
public void ignoreException() {
    assertThat(Stream.of(1,2,1,3).map(i -> 10 / i).reduce(0, Integer::sum), is(28));
    // the zero will break the next stream
    assertThat(Stream.of(1,2,0,3).map(i -> 10 / i).reduce(0, Integer::sum), is(18));
}
```

So the division by zero can break the whole stream.

I found a lot of articles that wrap a runtime exception in a checked exception (`throw new RuntimeException(ex)`).
Or partial vs. total functions.

Or I made a wrapper returning a java.util.function.Function
(e.g: `....map(wrapper(i -> 10/i))...`),
returning a "null" in the case of a exception. But right-hand operation may now fail,
as in my example (reduce).

The only useful approach is an "EITHER" concept (a stream of EITHER),
so the division by zero in my example
will become a "left" and can be handled in a different way.

Comment: before you reduce, you can `filter` nulls/invalid values out (and, if needed, in that filter, you could have them "handled in a different way" - a bit dirty but still... e.g. to log the element is going to be filter out)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko that is, of course, true. But if the operation(s) is(are) complex enough, the problem of "filtering out" can get disproportionally more complex (imagine generating SHA512-hashes and - for some obscure reason - hashes ending in a `0` will lead to an `Exception` being thrown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are relatively few operations on streams that can achieve a transformation of elements and result in elements being dropped -- in fact, there's really only one, `flatMap`.

So your wrapper more or less *has to* look like

```
interface CanThrow<F, T> { T apply(F from) throws Exception; }
<T, R> Function<T, Stream<R>> wrapper(CanThrow<T, R> fn) {
  return t -> {
   try {
    return Stream.of(fn.apply(t));
   } catch (Exception ignored) { return Stream.empty(); }
  }
}


assertThat(Stream.of(1, 2, 0, 3).flatMap(wrapper(i -> 10 / i)).reduce(0, Integer::sum))
   .isEqualTo(18));
```

Comment: Hello Louis. 
Exact the solution I'm looking for. Already tested :-). So the wrapper will "ignore" the elements in the stream and I do not have to "filter" later out as suggested by Andrew above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Test
public void ignoreException() {
assertThat(Stream.of(1,2,1,3).map(i -> i == 0 ? 0 : 10 / i).reduce(0, Integer::sum), is(28));
// the zero will break the next stream
assertThat(Stream.of(1,2,0,3).map(i -> i == 0 ? 0 : 10 / i).reduce(0, Integer::sum), is(18));
}
```